# How to install a toilet on raised flooring

Tags: toilet

I’ve had to raise the flooring in my basement by 3 inches and this means the bathroom floor will also be raised. I now have to install a toilet on top of a 2 inch foam barrier and 3/4 inch plywood. I’m concerned about the per/sq/inch force of the toilet, so was wondering if I should replace the foam with plywood in the area that that toilet will rest on.
I’m also assuming that the exit pipe (floor flange) can be raised with an extension?

Comment: You dont want a wax seal leak, so the toilet base must rigid and preferably water sealed.

Comment: There are toilet flange extensions but 3" might be a bit much. I'd much rather have the old flange cut out, the closet flange extended up and the new toilet flange screwed down into the new top layer of plywood. This would also allow  you to install wood backing under and around the toilet base/flange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that there is plywood on top of the foam to spread the load out, if you use even the usual lowest grade of XPS (not sure what type of foam you actually used or plan to use) it should not deform under load. That grade is 25PSI, so if the plywood spreads the load to 16 square inches of floor it should still hold up a 100 lb toilet and a 300 lb person - and in fact the load will be spread to much more floor area, with any normal toilet base and plywood. The one I recently installed was probably north of 200 square inches just for the toilet base area, but some are smaller.

You can also get higher grade foam - up to 100PSI is available, or you can use solid wood or masonry (won't rot, wood might eventually) right under the toilet if you'd feel better about those options. Cut a hole in the flooring system, extend the flange, pour concrete. That will stay put until someone remodels and comes at it with a hammer...